# Adding model to Backbone.Collection not refreshing view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am getting started with Backbone and here is my code located on jsfiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/KZyeV/2/

As you can see on the click of the button I am trying to add vehicle:

```
 addVehicle: function(){
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.add({Color:'black', Type: 'bicycle'});
        //this.render(); why do I have to again call render? without this it doesn't work.
    }
```

but for some reason it doesn't update the view unless I call `this.render();`. Is this the correct way? I've worked with Knockout and this is not how that works. When model is updated the view is updated automatically but for some reason the view is not updating here.

Comment: `this.collection.bind("reset add", this.render, this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add:

```
initialize: function(){            
    this.template = _.template($('#vehicleItemTemplate').html());
    this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);
},
```

Backbone doesn't react to collection changes automatically. If you want that, look into libraries like Marionette.js (which is built on top of Backbone).